# Nodes won't show up Blender 3.0

Tags: cycles-render-engine, materials, node-editor

I am pretty new to blender. I'd like to use nodes to create a material, but even though I have nodes enabled and used them to choose a Glass BSDF, and they are showing up in the properties panel, I can't see them in the node editor nor click anything in the node editor -- everything is greyed out. I am using cycles.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

You are in the Texture editor, it's a legacy editor to edit Blender pre-2.80 textures with nodes. What you are looking for is the Shader editor:

[image: shading editor]

And once you are there, make sure you are in the Object shader type to see your object's shaders:

[image]